# How can I use a TextView as a separator within a GridView?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a JSON-collection of elements which are separated in different groups and I want to show them in a `GridView` with their group names as `TextView` dividers. Is there a way to achieve this with one `GridView` instead of a `GridView` for each item?

```
Name of Group one    //(TextView)
[Item 1] [Item 2] [Item 3] [Item 4]
[Item 5] [Item 6]       

Name of Group two    //(TextView)
[Item 7] [Item 8] [Item 9] [Item 10] 
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use TableLayout instead

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_TableLayout_and_TableRow_Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you  will have to use simply for every group a own GridView,
or you can try a TableLayout which @buxik has recently posted below.